# Instanceof syntax error?

Tags: java, instanceof

I have an exercise which relates to "`instanceof`" and I am not quite sure how to use it. This is what I came up with:

```
for(int i = 4; i < 6; i++){
    int availSupply = part[i].stockLevel+part[i].getAvailForAssembly();
    if(availSupply instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println("Total number of items that can be supplied for "+ part[i].getID()+"(" + part[i].getName() + ": "+ availSupply);
    }
}
```

The code looks fine to me, however it came up with an error:

```
Multiple markers at this line

Incompatible conditional operand types int and Integer at:  if(availSupply instanceof Integer){
```

I do not know what I did wrong, it is the only error that showed up.

Comment: Why do you want to check instanceof with int ?

Comment: `int` is a Primitive Data Type while Integer is a class. `instanceof` operator does not work with Primitive Data Types. You should declare your `availSupply` variable as Integer. [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) [Java Wrapper Classes](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/java-wrapper-classes.php)

Comment: Hint for freshman learning Java: don't assume that concepts you haven't fully studied yet ... are "ok", because "they look fine". In programming, there is no such thing as looking fine. Compilers are deterministic; they analyze source code; and when a compiler is giving you an error message, then fine-looking doesn't matter. In that case, the thing to do is to read the error message carefully, and maybe open a book and study the concept that is pointed out to be used wrongly in more detail.

Comment: I am expected to use the instanceof somewhere in my code but i don't know where and how to use it i guess...

Comment: Instead of declaring availSupply as int declare it as Integer...

Comment: @ShaileshYadav Why? It would compile, but the test would still be redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `instanceof` with an expression of a primitive type, as you're doing here with `availSupply`. An `int` can't be anything else, after all.

If `getAvailForAssembly()` is already declared to return `int`, then you don't need your `if` statement at all - just unconditionally execute the body. If it returns `Integer`, you should probably use:

```
Integer availSupply = ...;
if (availSupply != null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here `int` is a primitive value and `instanceof` keyword checks for object belongs the class in your case i,e `Integer`.so `int` is itself a primitive value it is  not a `instance` of `class` `Integer`
below is basic snippets of `instanceof` keyword about use of it.

```
class InstanceofDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent obj1 = new Parent();
        Parent obj2 = new Child();

        System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Parent: "
            + (obj1 instanceof Parent));
        System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Child: "
            + (obj1 instanceof Child));
        System.out.println("obj1 instanceof MyInterface: "
            + (obj1 instanceof MyInterface));
        System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Parent: "
            + (obj2 instanceof Parent));
        System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Child: "
            + (obj2 instanceof Child));
        System.out.println("obj2 instanceof MyInterface: "
            + (obj2 instanceof MyInterface));
    }
}

class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface {}
interface MyInterface {}
```

**output:**

```
 obj1 instanceof Parent: true
   obj1 instanceof Child: false
   obj1 instanceof MyInterface: false
    obj2 instanceof Parent: true
    obj2 instanceof Child: true
    obj2 instanceof MyInterface: true
```

please go through this link for better understanding of `instanceof` keyword:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `instanceof` operator with variables of primitive types (such as `int`, `boolean` and `float`) because they can only contain the numbers/values that their name already tells you (integers for `int`, `true` or `false` for `boolean` and floating point numbers for `float`).

Variables whose types are classes, though, *can* be used with `instanceof` because classes can (usually) be extended. A variable `Foo variable` may also contain an instance of the class `Bar` (e.g. if `Bar extends Foo`), so you may actually need the `instanceof` operator here.